# Matlab Finding Non-Linear System Solution With Newtonian Method

Tags: matlab

I've been trying to solve this question with newtonian method but it gives me error. I already looked up my code many times but still could not find what is wrong. The question is:

[image]

And my matlab code is:

```
close all, clear, clc

tolerance = 0.01;
error = 1;
X = [1 1 1]';

while(error>tolerance)
   x = X(1); y = X(2); z = X(3); 
   F = [3*x^2-2*x*y+z^3-3 6*x+3*y^2-2*x*y*z-6 2*x*z+y^2-x*y*z^2-2]';
   J = [6*x-2*y -2*x 3*z^2; 6-2*y*z 6*y-2*x*z -2*x*y; 2*z-y*z^2 2*y-x*z^2 2*x-2*x*y];
   Xnew = X - J\F;
   error = norm(Xnew-X);
   X = Xnew;
end
```

Comment: Shouldn't the last element of  `J` be `2*x- 2*x*y*z` ?

Comment: Yes you are right, thank you! @SardarUsama

Answer (score 1):

Problems with derivation can be avoided by letting MATLAB do the hard work for you. This is something you can do with [symbolic variables](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/index.html) (if you have the symbolic toolbox available):

```
syms x y z
F = [3*x^2-2*x*y+z^3-3 6*x+3*y^2-2*x*y*z-6 2*x*z+y^2-x*y*z^2-2].';
J = jacobian(F,[x,y,z]);
```

Seeing how `J\F` can be computed analytically, you can evaluate that expression just once and arrive at some crazy expression for `f(x,y,z)` which you can either save as a `function out = gradFun(x,y,z)`, or use it as an argument for `matlabFunction` or `symfun` to convert it to a function handle:

```
gradFun = matlabFunction(J\F,'Vars',[x y z]);
```

Then in your loop you would use:

```
Xnew = X - gradFun(x0,y0,z0);
```